# plotting a pandas dataframe row by row

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have the following dataframe:

[image]

I want to create pie charts one for each row, the thing is that i am having trouble with the charts order, i want each chart to have a figsize of lets say 5,5 and that every row in my dataframe will be a row of plot in my subplots with the index as title.

tried many combinations and playing with pyploy.subplots but not success.
would be glad for some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either transpose your dataframe and using pandas pie kind for plotting, i.e. `df.transpose().plot(kind='pie', subplots=True)` or iterate through rows while sub plotting.

An example using subplots:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Recreate a similar dataframe
rows = ['rows {}'.format(i) for i in range(5)]
columns = ['hits', 'misses']
col1 = np.random.random(5)
col2 = 1 - col1
data = zip(col1, col2)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=rows, columns=columns)

# Plotting

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))

for i, (name, row) in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
    ax = plt.subplot(2,3, i+1)
    ax.set_title(row.name)
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    ax.pie(row, labels=row.index)

plt.show()
```

[image: piecharts]